# Validation rule not firing

Tags: formula, validation

Facing Error with this Validation . This validation is Ensuring The Name field is not blank
At least one of the following fields is blank: Company_c, .. etc.
At least one of the fields mentioned above has been changed (except for when the record is being created)
The Email__c field contains an "@" symbol
The Website__c field meets one of the following conditions:
Contains "http://" but not "www."
..etc .

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(Name))
  OR(
    ISBLANK(Company__c),
    ISBLANK(Contact_Number__c),
    ISBLANK(Email__c),
    ISBLANK(Industry__c),
    ISBLANK(Lead_Source__c),
    ISBLANK(NumberOfEmployees__c),
    ISBLANK(Website__c)
  ),
  OR(
    ISNEW()
    NOT(ISCHANGED(Company__c)),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(Contact_Number__c)),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(Email__c)),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(Industry__c)),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(Lead_Source__c)),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(NumberOfEmployees__c)),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(Website__c))
  ),
  NOT(CONTAINS(Email__c, '@'))
  OR(
    AND(
      CONTAINS(Website__c, 'http://'),
      NOT(CONTAINS(Website__c, 'www.'))
    ),
    AND(
      NOT(CONTAINS(Website__c, 'http://'))
      CONTAINS(Website__c, 'www.')
    ),
    NOT(CONTAINS(Website__c, '.'))
  )
  NOT(
    AND(
      CONTAINS(Contact_Number__c, '('),
      CONTAINS(Contact_Number__c, ')'),
      CONTAINS(Contact_Number__c, '-')
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `,` after some conditions .
Here is the shorter and Easier form of your validation rule :

```
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(Name)),
OR(
ISBLANK(Company__c),
ISBLANK(Contact_Number__c),
ISBLANK(Email__c),
ISBLANK(Industry__c),
ISBLANK(Lead_Source__c),
ISBLANK(NumberOfEmployees__c),
ISBLANK(Website__c)
),
NOT(
ISCHANGED(Company__c) ||
ISCHANGED(Contact_Number__c) ||
ISCHANGED(Email__c) ||
ISCHANGED(Industry__c) ||
ISCHANGED(Lead_Source__c) ||
ISCHANGED(NumberOfEmployees__c) ||
ISCHANGED(Website__c) ||
ISNEW()
),
NOT(CONTAINS(Email__c, '@')),
NOT(REGEX(Website__c, '((http://|https://)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.)?)')),
NOT(REGEX(Contact_Number__c, '
\d
3
\d3\d{3}-\d{4}'))
)
```

It simplifies the second OR condition by combining it with the NOT(ISCHANGED...) condition using the logical OR operator.

Hope it helps.